# Fire click event for only one element with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple div's with the same class name: `ag-list-item`

```
<!-- item one -->
<div class="ag-list-item">
</div>

<!-- item two -->
<div class="ag-list-item">
</div>

<!-- item three -->
<div class="ag-list-item">
</div>
```

They are dynamically created through an angular grid library I'm using, so I cannot set an ID attribute for any specific one.

I'm looking for a way to target only one specific div with the class name through a click event.

`$('.ag-list-item').click()` executes on all three elements; is there a way to only target one?

---

Update: 09/09/15

I found a solution that allows for specific index selection of a collection of div's with the same class, using the [:eq() selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

```
// select .ag-list-item at index 1
$('.ag-list-item:eq('1')').click();
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I have thought. But in my fiddle test, I forgot the simple quote around the number : eq('1'), so I hadn't post it. Anyway, delight to have helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As promised, I have done an update of my post.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // If you want to select the first element :
    $('.ag-list-item:first span span').click(function () {
        // Your code
    });

    // If you want to select the second element, in this example
    // Don't forget the quotes around the desired number
    $('.ag-list-item:eq("1") span span').click(function () {
        // Your code
    });

    // If you want the last element :
    $('.ag-list-item:last span span').click(function () {
        // Your code
    });

)};
```

Please find the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/5xLktbh7/) associated to this example (I have put some design style to a better understanding)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Are the clicks for the span with the class ag-visible-icons?

Comment: @KrakenDev It is not specified in the question

Comment: I'm assuming because ag-list-item span span would end up on the icons class, my answer requires knowing if that is the targeted class

Comment: Is there a way to target at a specific index (2, 3, etc.) instead of just the first?

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger KrankenDev's vanilla JS answer allows you to use a specific index

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger Ya man just pass the index you want to the els[] selector eg. els[1], els[2] etc..

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure Javascript solution for speed, this could do the trick:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-visible-icons');

els[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Do something
});
```

For jQuery you could try:

```
$('.ag-visible-icons').first().click(function() {
  // Do somehting
});
```

This is assuming the class you showed the the '.ag-list-item:first span span' path is the ag-visible-icon class

Comment: That vanilla JS example would be great but it's not actually firing a click event for me

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger It should be, are you using Chrome? I tested it in JsFiddle before posting it and put some text inside the .ag-visible-icons span and then alerted that text on click and it worked.

Comment: Here you go, this will ONLY alert FOO (clicking first span)
http://jsfiddle.net/4m4jobz2/